# Setting password field to 'required' in Sails Mongo blocks beforeCreate

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, bcrypt, sails-mongo

My API uses SailsJs and MongoDb. For user creation, I am using the `beforeCreate lifecycle callback` to run bcrypt to hash my password field.

I encounter this wierd error, wherein if I set my encrPassword field to

```
{required : true}
```

my code stops working and emits the following error :

```
 {
  "error": "E_VALIDATION",
  "status": 400,
  "summary": "1 attribute is invalid",
  "model": "User",
  "invalidAttributes": {
    "encrPassword": [
      {
        "rule": "string",
        "message": "Value should be a string (instead of null, which is an object)"
      },
      {
        "rule": "required",
        "message": "\"required\" validation rule failed for input: null\nSpecifically, it threw an error.  Details:\n undefined"
      }
    ]
  }
```

here is my code sample :

```
attributes: {
    fullname : {type : 'string'},
    username : {type : 'string', unique:true, required:true},
    encrPassword : {type : 'string'}, // ==> this works
    // encrPassword : {type : 'string', required:true}, ==> this doesn't
},

insert : function(req, cb){
    console.log('Insert ', req);
    if(typeof req.fullName == 'string' && typeof req.username == 'string'){
        User.findOne({username : req.username}).exec(function(err, res){
            if(!res){
                User.create(req).exec(function(err, resp){
                    console.log('create', null, resp);
                    if(err)
                      cb(err);
                    else cb(null, resp);
                });
            }
            else cb({message: 'already eists'})
        });
    }
    else cb({message: 'Bad Request'});
},

beforeCreate : function(req, next){
    console.log('In bcrypt');
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
        if(err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(req.password, salt, function(err, hash){
            if(err) return next(err);
            req.encrPassword = hash;
            delete req.password;
            console.log('Leaving BCrypt'); 
            next();
        });
    });
}
```

ps. I rigorously checked for typos; any typos or syntax errors in the above sample are the result of editing to hide any code i wouldnt want to share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is done before calling `beforeCreate`.
There is no `encrPassword` at that moment, hence the error.